# PUT Method errors out when model string has value with webapi

Tags: angularjs, ajax, viewmodel, put

I have this webapi method here:

```
// PUT api/Competitions/5
public HttpResponseMessage PutCompetitor(int id, CompetitionViewModel competitorviewmodel)
{
     ...
}
```

The CompetitionViewModel looks something like this:

```
public class CompetitionViewModel
{
    public int CompetitorId { get; set; }
    public string Owned{ get; set; }
    public bool Sold { get; set; }
}
```

I have an angular http.put call to update a competition model that looks like this:

```
$scope.updateProject = function () {
    $http.put(mvc.base + "API/Projects/" + masterScopeTracker.ProjectID, $scope.ProjectCRUD)
        .success(function (result) {
        })
        .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            masterScopeTracker.autoSaveFail;
        });
}
```

On page load, a new competition is created. So I have a model like the following:

```
{
    CompetitorId: 56,
    Owned: null,
    Sold: false
}
```

Every 15 seconds a call to update the model is made. If I don't change any of the values of the model, the webapi put method gets called and runs successfully without a problem. If I change the model to this:

```
{
    CompetitorId: 56,
    Owned: "Value",
    Sold: false
}
```

I get a 500 Error and the method is not hit. Not understanding what I am doing wrong here. The view model accepts a string. A string is being sent in the payload. Yet I get the error. Anyone have any ideas?

UPDATE:

I was able to get the server to give me this error:

```
{"Message":"Anerrorhasoccurred.",
    "ExceptionMessage":"Objectreferencenotsettoaninstanceofanobject.",
    "ExceptionType":"System.NullReferenceException",
    "StackTrace":"atClientVisit.Models.ClientVisitEntities.SaveChanges()\r\natClientVisit.Controllers.API.CompetitionsController.PutCompetitor(Int32id,CompetitionViewModelcompetitorviewmodel)\r\natlambda_method(Closure,Object,Object[])\r\natSystem.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass13.<GetExecutor>b__c(Objectinstance,Object[]methodParameters)\r\natSystem.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.Execute(Objectinstance,Object[]arguments)\r\natSystem.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpers.RunSynchronously[TResult](Func`1func,CancellationTokencancellationToken)"
}
```

I should also say that this doesn't happen locally. This only happens when deployed on the clients server.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the event log to see what the actual error is on the server side.  I've had trouble with IIS/IIS Express before with Put because WebDAV was enabled.  You can disable it in your web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
        <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
    </modules>
    <handlers>
        <remove name="WebDAV" />
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: From googling and such I have already tried the webdav setting in the web config. I'm trying to find the server event logs but having trouble. Client's machine is pretty locked down.

Comment: Another thing that would lead me to the WebDAV conclusion is the fact that your not seeing the Put method on the controller getting hit.  Another thing to check is the routes and the parameter names you're using.  If you're not using 'id', you may need to add a new route to handle it.

Comment: I was able to get the server to send me a more descriptive error. Perhaps you might have additional input?

Comment: Ah, I see you updated the question with the error.  It looks like you have a problem in your data model to sort out.  Null Exception means you're trying to use an object that is null or hasn't been initialized (or both).

Comment: Turns out that the error logging we implemented into the system was making the put methods take longer to complete. This eventually would just error out because the information being sent would no longer be populated. Took way to long to figure this one out -.-;